# Weird notice: The text_direction option is deprecated for the family of bloginfo()

Tags: wordpress, deprecation-warning

After updating WordPress I am getting this notice (below).

I have searched through all files on this install and `bloginfo('text_direction')` is not being used anywhere.

Any ideas peeps?

Thanks

```
Notice: get_bloginfo was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.2!
The text_direction option is deprecated for the family of bloginfo() functions. 
Use the is_rtl() function instead. 
in .../html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3508
```

Comment: Just leave it, it is a notice only. disable error notice in php.ini file

Comment: Thank you Tamil. I am aware it is only a notice. Nevertheless, it is annoying (I am working in a development environment) - and would want to know how this is being caused anyway.

Comment: For each version of wordpress upgrade, they provide some new functions as well as deprecated some function. So the notice is shown.

Comment: Tamil, I am aware of this. My query is to why I am getting this notice.  `bloginfo('text_direction')` is not being used in any theme or plugin on this install.

Comment: @TamilSelvan "Disable error notice" is the worst advice I've read on SO in a long time. richerimage, it has to be somewhere...or you wouldn't be seeing the error. Have you tried disabling all plugins one by one? How about switching to a different theme temporarily to see if it is in fact the theme. If the error goes away, you've discovered where the problem is.

Comment: @rnevius - yes, I had a typo in my search query looking for `text_dirextion' - it was in my theme after all! All sorted now, thank you.

p.s. - Fixing is better than sweeping under the carpet :)